# How to add Modal pop up on nodes of org chart Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, getorgchart

I have working on a highchart Page where I need show my data when i clicked on a nodes of an org chart.
I'm able to show the data onclick of nodes but that is a tooltip. My requirement is need to show the data onclick of nodes but that should ne modal popup.
Here's my code

[https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2e83ngw1/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using tooltip, you can create your own popup element, update it with a point info and show/hide it in the point's events.

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      const popup = document.getElementById('popup');

      popup.innerHTML = this.info;
      popup.style.display = 'block';

    },
    mouseOut: function() {
      const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
      popup.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dhaysfqz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.point.events

Comment: I want to close my modal by clicking on close button not mouseout

Comment: And also I want when I clicked on the nodes that time tooltip should not visible on hover. But after clicking on close button on hover tooltip should be visible

Comment: Hi @Rika Das, Ok, thanks for more details. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sf12xykj/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek . now my code is working properly

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , I need one more help.. what if I want to show another org chart as a modal popup onclick of node . is it possible? can you please guide me

Comment: I will answer you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684894/onclick-of-a-org-chart-another-org-chart-will-open-as-a-modal-popup

Comment: yeah sure 
thanks you for your reply and help