# Onclick of a org chart another org chart will open as a modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts, orgchart

I'm working on a Hichcharts project where my requirement is i need to show a modal popup onclick of a org chart's node. And the popup should be another org chart.
here's is my code

```
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ritzlucky13/p83khLrw/
```

Can anyone please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another organization chart in a popup. Example:

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      ...
      Highcharts.chart(popupContent, {
        ...
        series: [{
          type: 'organization',
          data: [
            ['CEO', 'Department1'],
            ['CEO', 'Department2'],
            ['CEO', 'Department3']
          ]
        }]
      });
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mo32e6v1/

Comment: But if I want different chart(org chart only but data are different) onclick of different node . is this possible?

Comment: Hi @Rika Das, Yes of course. You can set the new created chart data based on clicked point. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/te0kd6f5/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , but there some nodes doesn't have data. so the popup is showing blank.
in my case i just want 3 nodes that has data . so on click of those nodes popup will open and those doesn't have data for those node there should not be any popup

Comment: You just need to add a simple condition. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tejgzx49/